# find best optimum scale value

Tags: algorithm, collision-detection, mathematical-optimization

I am doing project for optimization. It has two 3D models first 3D model is fixed static and another 3D model is deformable (it changes it's scale value).

For Initial scale value second model I need to find maximum scale value that contained with thin the first model. My current implementation is described here in 4 steps.

1. Start with initial scale = 1 and position second model contained in first model
2. Create collision model of both objects using AABB tree.
3. Now I increase scale value by factor scale += 0.01 and rebuild the second model tree.
4. Now check for collision if second model hit first model then stop loop and it will be final scale value.

I am doing this way at moment but speed is very slow due to collision detection checking in while loop and tree building.

What is the best method or algorithm to do this?

Comment: Why would you rebuild the tree? Couldn't you just transform it? Or not change it at all and introduce scale data in the collision detection? What kinds of models are we talking about? Are they convex? You could improve the performance by using a smarter step strategy. E.g. try to double the scale as many times as possible. If that's not possible, go with 1.5, then 1.25 and so on. This time you should be faster at the final scale.

Comment: I need to rebuild the tree because i am changing vertex position by scale and i am using AABBTree . I am using convex and concave both type of models.  can you explain more about smarter step strategy ?

Comment: Using any algorithm can decide alpha value faster ?

Comment: The structure of the tree won't change when you scale the object. Only the coordinates will be scaled. That's why you don't need to rebuild the tree.

Comment: Actually i am not rebuilding tree but i am doing refit the tree. Change only vertex of tree. Sorry it was mistake.